# Controlling the bubble chart size in highchart that having same z axis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have the data option for bubble highchart as:
 data:[{x: 1.8, y: 2, z: 1}, {x: 1.2,y: 1, z: 1},{x: 2.6, y: 1, z: 1}]

The size of bubble coming as default. I need to override this and give size smaller than the default size. In short I want smaller and equal size bubble.

Comment: what about http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bubble.maxSize and http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bubble.minSize ?

Comment: No, maxSize and minSize is not helping because I have same z axis

Comment: I don't understand, can you create a Fiddle? If you have n Bubbles with a z-Value of 1 for each of them, then the resulting size will be `maxSize` for all of them.

Comment: It works for me, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h0Lpbb83/

Comment: Solved with minSize and maxSize only, earlier I was doing some other thing wrong, thanks